# Insert DIV before TABLE

Tags: html, css

I simply want to insert a DIV containing some text before a table element.

I tried this but the text gets inserted between thead and the first data row and the table's first column gets disturbed because of the inserted text.

What would be the proper solution to this? I can't add class names to the table element as I have to apply this style to existing legacy content.

Here is the **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLeby3s0/1/)**.

CSS:

```
table:before {
    content:"this text should use the whole width of the table!";
}
```

Comment: You wont be able to insert a div this with CSS pseudo elements. You could use javascript to insert the div though.

Comment: Why do you want it in a pseudo class??

Comment: I can only modify the CSS, I can not change the content (HTML) itself. In addition, that extra text should only appear on small devices, so I am looking for a CSS trick to be used within a media query. The result should be: on small devices I will see the table and a little text note before the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

Sorry i just miss in previous post:

**CSS**

```
table:before {
    content:"this text should use the whole width of the table!";
}

table
{
    display:block;
}
```

[UPDATED:DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yLeby3s0/6/)

Comment: Thanks!! I missed the `display:block` property on the table. You're the man.